# Append text at after the url with the help of jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code to grab a url from a clicked link:

```
var newurl = $(this).attr('href');
```

I want to add a string to that url.

For example, my current url is:

mydomain/test.jsp

I want to make it:

http://testdomain.com/mydomain/test.jsp

What should I do to achive this ?

I'd be grateful for your advice!

here is the try fildde
http://jsfiddle.net/GLw6W/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like I may be missing what you mean, but I think you just want to do:

```
var newurl = 'http://testdomain.com/' + $(this).attr('href');
$(this).attr('href', newurl);
```

Comment: not able to do this.May be i am doing some mistake can you please make it in fiddle ? i will be glad

Comment: hey its not routing the url to the page

Comment: window.location.href = newurl;

Comment: no its not working can you please do this for me on fiddle ? i will be very thankfull to u bro

Comment: like i said, I don't entirely get what you want to have happen.  Explain it a little more and maybe I can help.

Comment: i have a relative path (mydomain/test.jsp ) on my href but once i click on that anchor tag i want to add one absolute url like http://testdomain.com and it should be likehttp://testdomain.com/mydomain/test.jsp